# Meaning of "IndentationError: expected an indented block" exception?

Tags: python

I am learning Python but...don't understand what this error means.

```
>>> for edad in range(10, 18): #Que nos muestre la edad de 10 a 18 (Errores causados por los dos puntos)...   File "<stdin>", line 2
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: What do you plan to do in your for loop?

Comment: We need the entire context in a form we can reproduce.  From this, it merely appears that you neglected to indent the next line.  Python *requires* indentation for blocks.  Can you post at least two lines that show the problem?

Comment: You entered a blank line following the beginning of the `for` loop. The Python console expects you to enter valid lines of code until the entire body of the loop has been input. The block (one or more lines of code) for the body following the first line of a `for` loop must all be indented. You can workaround the problem by entering a tab character or one or more (usually four) spaces on each line after the first.

Comment: Hey, we all started somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to go on here, but after a for statement such as this, you need a line after this and 4 spaces before your next statement. A lot of programming languages use `{` and `}` to signify the start and stop of a block of code, Python uses indentation (4 spaces) to do this. Your code should look something like:

```
for edad in range(10, 18):
    print(edad)
```

Comment: pass would maybe be a better choice for second line in this example :)